# Disable convert string when post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How I can disable replacing string from URL when post via AJAX?
For example, when

```
$.ajax({
    action: '/',
    method: 'post',
    data:{
        test: '%%23 abc%%'
    },
    success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
});
```

and dump it on server, I see "**%# abc%%**".
How I can resolve this trouble?

Comment: Are you calling `urldecode` in the server script? If you are, don't do that.

Comment: you can _decode_ it on the server side, to see you original string.

Answer (score 0):

You're presumably calling `urldecode()` on the server. You don't need to do this explicitly, it's done automatically by PHP when processing POST data or URL parameters. As a result, you're decoding the value twice, which goes too far because it interprets your literal percents as part of URL encoding.